# symfony wrong value into db after file upload

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-3.3

I've created a form to upload images and the upload itself is working, but the wrong value gets written into the database.
This is the code in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use AppBundle\Service\FileUploader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
 /**
     * @Route("/bearbeiten/{id}", name="edit")
     */
     public function editAction($id, Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader){
 $user = new Users();
        //Formular wird erstellt
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($listen)
               ->add('bild', FileType::class, array('required'=>false, 'label'=>'Bild (JPEG-Datei)', 'data_class'=>null))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Speichern', 'attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')))
                ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        //Falls die Form valid ist....
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->get('save')->isClicked()){

            //Daten aus der Form in Variabeln sichern
             $file = $form['bild']->getData();
             $filename = $fileUploader->upload($file);
             dump($filename);
             $user->setBild($filename);

             return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
         }
}
}
```

The service *FileUploader* is stored in *FileUploader.php* and has the following code:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


class FileUploader
{
     private $targetDir;
     public function __construct($targetDir) {
         $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
     }
     public function upload(UploadedFile $file) {
         $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
         $file->move($this->getTargetDir(), $fileName);
         return $fileName;
     }
     public function getTargetDir() {
         return $this->targetDir;
     }
}
```

I've also defined the service in *services.yml*:

```
  AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
           $targetDir: '%file_directory%'
```

...and declared the variable *file_directory* in  config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
    file_directory: '/tmp'
```

Now when I dump the variabel **$filename**, I get the value back I expect, 2d504a8e0a9daba27e7baab69dc08896.jpeg as an example, but even though I use the same variabel to save the string into my database `$user->setBild($filename);`, another value gets written into my table. 
Example of the value in my db: */tmp/phpn7rb2i*

I'm really confused and appreciate any help.
Hopefully some of you can help me overcome this.

Comment: where do you persist and flush ?

Comment: you just move file to some location, but you forget to add the filename in entity field.

Comment: Take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html , that will give you some good lines to follow to handle file upload :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DefaultController` you get the `$filename` via the `FileUploader`. You set that `$filename` to the `$user` via `$user->setBild($filename);` but you never persist that user to your database. Since you redirect just after that, the value in `$filename` as well as `$user` are lost.

You need to persist the data via the Entity Manager like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Since you seem to have a value inside your database, that value was either there from the beginning and never changes, or you persist at some other point, but whatever it is you persist, it is not the value you had in `$filename` in your `editAction` inside your `DefaultController`.

Comment: it worked^^ thanks a lot :) was stuck way too long because of that. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You need to call persist and flush on the entity manager to save your new User to database, like so (in controller):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = new User();
$user->setBild($filename);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```